# Images does not show up

Tags: codeigniter

I wonder what's wrong with my codes that the image does not show up as it suppose to.  Nothing appears.  Just blank.  I expect an image would appears.

views/editgalleries.php

```
<?php foreach ($pictures as $pictures_item): ?>                     
<td><br><img src="<?php echo base_url('../uploads/'); ?><?php echo $pictures_item['galleries_picture_name']; ?>" height="300" width="200"></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Cpages.php

```
public function edit_galleries_picture() 
{       
    $gallery_id = $this->uri->segment(3);       
    $data['pictures'] = $this->Mpages->call_gallery_pictures($gallery_id);      
    $this->load->view('editgalleries', $data);      
}
```

models/Mpages.php

```
public function call_gallery_pictures($gallery_id)
{
    $this->db->where('gallery_id', $gallery_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('galleries_pictures');
    return $query->result_array();      
}
```

Comment: check your source code image url is right or wrong

Comment: in your `base_url('uploads/')` don't use `..` uploads folder must be out side of application folder

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that have worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

set uploads folder in root directory and try this code

```
<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$pictures_item['galleries_picture_name']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads'); ?>/<?php echo $pictures_item['galleries_picture_name']; ?>" height="300" width="200">
```

Note that for the `'base_url('../uploads/')'`,
the `'../'` part is not required because it's give your host name.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.